# ¿Cómo hago el pseudocódico o lo programo en C#? (usar ciclo while)

Tags: c#, while

El usuario de un sistema desea conectarse a una computadora por escritorio remoto.

El sistema debe:

1. Validar si la *IP* es correcta para la conexión. En caso de que no lo sea el sistema debe mostrar en pantalla un mensaje de **conexion fallida** y mostrarle la opcion de si desea o no intentarlo nuevamente. En caso de ser negativa la respuesta el usuario abandona la conexión.
2. Luego de validar la *IP* el sistema debe solicitar el usuario y la contraseña.
3. El sistema solo permite 3 intentos de conexión. Si el usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos, se muestra un mensaje en pantalla de **usuario y contraseña incorrectos**, de lo contrario se muestra un mensaje de **conexión satisfactoria**.

Comment: Hola Marcela, bienvenida. ¿Podrías indicarnos el problema explicito que tienes para desarrollar el pseudocódigo? Así mismo, proporcionarnos lo que has trabajado hasta el momento.

Comment: hola @JYass lo que sucede es que me dejaron esta actividad en la que debo utilizar el ciclo while, y estoy confundida que enunciado (true) debo utilizar en el while y así mismo el IP que tipo de dato seria el más adecuado. Agradecería en alto grado que me colaboraras con esto a ver si así puedo solucionar el ejercicio.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[En el sitio de codeproject hay un ejemplo que te puede servir de referencia.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET)

Puedes hacer un ciclo While que verifiqué la conexión y dentro del ciclo llevar un contador del número de intentos fallidos. Como condición del While usa una bandera del estado de la conexión.