# Unas dudas de código

Tags: c#

muy buenas tardes, (no voy a mentir, me dejaron un trabajo que debo solucionar para mañana utilizando ciclos while, y hasta ahora estoy aprendiendo programación) lo que sucede es que al realizar el codigo me salieron bastantes dudas que al buscar en internet lo único que hicieron fue enredarme más, me gustaría que alguien me pudiera aclarar las dudas que aparecen en los comentarios del código.

*si solo me van a regañar por no entender por favor no comenten, todos tenemos errores... gracias*

El trabajo debe hacer esto:

- a) Validar si la IP es correcta para la conexión, en caso de que no lo sea el sistema debe mostrar en pantalla un mensaje de conexión fallida y mostrarle la opción de si desea o no intentarlo nuevamente en caso de ser negativa la respuesta el usuario abandona la conexión.
- b) Luego de validar la dirección IP el sistema debe solicitar el usuario y la contraseña solo se permite 3 intentos de conexión, Si el usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos se muestra un mensaje en pantalla de usuario y contraseña incorrectos" en caso contrario se muestra un mensaje de conexión satisfactoria.

.

```
namespace Escritorio_Remoto
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Se inicia conociendo que el usuario es 1234 y la contraseña es 0000.
            string user, pass, res, IP;
            int intentos = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("----Bienvenido al Escritorio Remoto----");
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la IP a la que desea conectarse: ");
            IP = Console.ReadLine();
            //Como hago para que la IP puede tener puntos y sea valida, pues me aparece el error que como es string o puedo usar '<='
            IP = 0000;
            while (IP<=255255255255)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("La IP ingresada es correcta.");
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese Usuario: ");
                user = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese La Contraseña: ");
                pass = Console.ReadLine(); Console.Clear();
                user = "1234";
                pass="0000";
                intentos += 1;
                if ((pass == "0000")&&(user == "1234"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Conexión Satisfactoria, Bienveni@ " + user);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else 
                {
                    //no se como repetir la solicitud de usuario y contraseña, para que el contador llegue a tres y envie el mensaje de "Ha alcanzado el número máximo de intentos."
                    Console.WriteLine("Ha alcanzado el número máximo de intentos.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Usuario y Contraseña Incorrectas.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Conexión Fallida.");
            Console.WriteLine("Desea intentarlo nuevamente? S/N");
            res = Console.ReadLine();
            if(res=="N")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ha abandonado la conexión...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (res=="S")
            {
                //No se como hacer para repetir todo desde la solicitud del IP
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega información acerca de que es lo que tenes que validar con el IP

Comment: Hice esto hace unos años, espero te sea de utilidad: https://github.com/fredyfx/Curso-Programando-En-One

Comment: Tu pregunta está por ser cerrada, tiene 2 votos de "No está claro lo que se pregunta" y 1 voto de "demasiado amplia". Te puedo recomendar que edites tu pregunta y agregues o hagas referencia a la pregunta [¿Cómo hago el pseudocódico o lo programo en C#?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56397/c%C3%B3mo-hago-el-pseudoc%C3%B3dico-o-lo-programo-en-c-usar-ciclo-while) para que al menos puedan ayudarte. Al final, las respuestas no te lleven por la tangente. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo así:

[Ejemplo online en funcionamiento](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aYqJOF)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         // Se inicia conociendo que el usuario es 1234 y la contraseña es 0000.
            string user, pass, res, IP;
            int intentos = 0;
            int maxIntentos = 3;
            Console.WriteLine("----Bienvenido al Escritorio Remoto----");
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la IP a la que desea conectarse: ");
            IP = Console.ReadLine();
            //Como hago para que la IP puede tener puntos y sea valida, pues me aparece el error que como es string o puedo usar '<='
            //IP = 0000;
            while (Convert.ToInt32(IP)<=255255255255 && intentos <= (maxIntentos +1))//Debes chequear los intentos en el while
            {
                Console.WriteLine("La IP ingresada es correcta.");
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese Usuario: ");
                user = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese La Contraseña: ");
                pass = Console.ReadLine(); 

                //user = "1234";
                //pass="0000";
                intentos += 1;
                if ((pass == "0000")&&(user == "1234"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Conexión Satisfactoria, Bienveni@ " + user);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else 
                {
                    //no se como repetir la solicitud de usuario y contraseña, para que el contador llegue a tres y envie el mensaje de "Ha alcanzado el número máximo de intentos."
                    if(intentos >= maxIntentos){
                        Console.WriteLine("Ha alcanzado el número máximo de intentos.");
                    }else{
                        Console.WriteLine("Usuario y Contraseña Incorrectas.");
                    }                                        
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Conexión Fallida.");
            Console.WriteLine("Desea intentarlo nuevamente? S/N");
            res = Console.ReadLine();
            if(res=="N")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ha abandonado la conexión...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (res=="S")
            {
                Main();//Asi llamas a que se corra todo nuevamente
                //No se como hacer para repetir todo desde la solicitud del IP
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque el voto negativo? En el código mismo explico la solución..

Comment: Se ve que alguno porque no pusiste el código en la pagina, ahí te di uno positivo para equilibrar

Comment: Si, que extraño, lo agregue a la página también por las dudas. Gracias

Comment: Con enlace o no, la respuesta no es útil porque realmente es solo código sin explicación.  Si es que hay explicaciones en comentarios, son pocos, no se destacan de los comentarios de OP, y definitivamente hay cambios no explicados. Tampoco me parece buena idea el que llames al Main de forma recursiva. En fin, no creo que realmente le estás haciendo un favor a OP con esta respuesta.

Comment: @sstan entiendo lo que decís y pienso que siempre se pueden hacer las cosas mejor claro, pero me pareció por el tipo de pregunta, que hay muchos conceptos básicos que aun no tiene claros quien preguntó y agregándole complejidad a la respuesta no iba a ayudar, sino que se iba a mezclar más. Pero bueno, todas las opiniones son bienvenidas :)

Answer (score 1):

> // Se inicia conociendo que el usuario es 1234 y la contraseña es
>   0000.

Si sabes que inicia con esos valores se los podes asignar cuando declaras la variable

```
string user="1234", pass="0000", res, IP;
```

> //Como hago para que la IP puede tener puntos y sea valida, pues me
>   aparece el error que como es string o puedo usar '<='

Si queres que la IP tenga puntos tiene que ser string, vos la estas declarando string y le estas pasando 0000 que es un int

> //no se como repetir la solicitud de usuario y contraseña, para que el
>   contador llegue a tres y envie el mensaje de "Ha alcanzado el número
>   máximo de intentos."

```
while (intentos<3 && La otra condicion si acierta)
{

}
```

> //No se como hacer para repetir todo desde la solicitud del IP
>   Esto lo pones en todo el codigo desde donde empieza, tene en cuenta que dentro del Do While tenes que modificar la variable res

```
 do{

    }while (res=="S")
```

--

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese Usuario: ");
user = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese La Contraseña: ");
pass = Console.ReadLine(); Console.Clear();
user = "1234";
pass="0000";
intentos += 1;
if ((pass == "0000")&&(user == "1234"))
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Conexión Satisfactoria, Bienveni@ " + user);
     Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Para que haces que ingrese usuario y contraseña si abajo los pones vos por código, ademas de que el if ese siempre va a ser positivo